# Prevent change detection from Injectable

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I'm polling a server every second in an injectable, but it's triggering change detection through the whole app, causing scrolling to jitter every second.

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1z9hbx

Is there any way to prevent this without NgZone.runOutsideAngular?

Doing NgZone.runOutsideAngular would make interceptors (which in my case can show modals) also run outside angular... Which is bad?

Why is changes in an injectable triggering changes in the root component?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the doCheck triggering the change detection, not the polling?

From the docs:

> A lifecycle hook that invokes a custom change-detection function for a
>   directive, in addition to the check performed by the default
>   change-detector.

Comment: The documentation is unclear? I am understanding it as a callback after angular's own change detector has run for the implementor

Comment: It seems a little unclear, I had to read a couple of times at least

Comment: Have you seen this: https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/